# WebRequest.GetResponseStream() failing in ASP.NET MVC 3 project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I'm trying to perform a programmatic HTTP POST in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. The aim is to mimic a form submission.

I'm using the following code (modified slightly for confidentiality):

```
string input = "foo=bar";
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://my.domain.com/endpoint");

request.ContentLength = data.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";

using ( var stream = request.GetRequestStream() ) {
    stream.Write(request);
    stream.Close();
}

var response = request.GetResponse();

// get the response data, do backflips, save the world
```

The problem is, I'm getting an error during the `.GetRequestStream()` call, saying that I couldn't connect to the URL resource.

However, if I plug in **the exact same code** in a console application, I can connect just fine. A colleague also managed to connect using the same code in a WCF service application.

This is driving me nuts. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: First obvious difference would be the security related to a console app and a site is different. Try fiddle with your security profiles - what type of user are you running as? See if that helps

Comment: Also make sure that that user has permission to make that call in the firewall (port 80).

Comment: @rangitatanz ~ Yeah, thought of that too --- that's why there was a WCF service application test as well. But definitely will look more into this.

Comment: yeah but you said 'a colleague' - did you run that on your system?

Comment: @rangitatanz ~ yup. sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Is it only this site or all sites? Like if you change it to google or another site what happens?

Comment: Also can you have a look what Fiddler says is happening?

Comment: Also I've been trying to google that error and can't find it. What exception is that?

Comment: @rangitatanz ~ Unfortunately, we gave up and switched our project build to use the VS dev server, instead of the local IIS. That worked, which suggests that it may just be some hidden hoodwink with securities and identities. Ugh. If you can pattern your initial comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a security issue to me.

To fix try the following:

- Fiddle with the security context your asp.net is running as.
- Ensure that the firewall is set up correctly - try disable it for a quick check.
- Drop back to using the ASP.net dev server to test with [;)]

If this doesnt work then can you please add more info e.g. Fiddler logs, stack trace.